# How to modify and commit phantom record without enabling "PATCH" proxy request

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I'm linking a phantom record to a form, but I need to populate the phamtom record with some preloaded data:

```
let rec = this.window.getModelView().data.myRec:
rec.set('date_field','2020-01-01');
```

In order to remove dirtiness, I'm committing:

```
rec.commit():
```

The reason I want to remove the dirtiness is to allow the user to close the window without warnings (some logic I've implemented to prevent closing the window when the record has been changed. In this case, since the data is preloaded, doesn't count as a real modification).

If I commit(), after running rec.save(), a PATCH request will be executed, instead of a POST, which is expected since the record is no longer phantom after commit.

So, is there a way to "unphantom" the record?
Or can I remove the dirtiness without committing?

Thanks.

Comment: After the commit, can't you just do `rec.phantom = true`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the option **{dirty: false}** when setting values

```
rec.set('date_field', '2020-01-01', {dirty: false});
```

instead of committing the record